# Insert Records All At Once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has been functional and i added a column to the table. After adding the column i want to add the result of a query (query is same for all but different results) into that column all at once instead of one at a time which will be time consuming. How can i achieve that? Cos after updating, i have just one result in all the column, i cannot use a where clause cos it will require me doing it one after the other

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE table SET my_value = '$myValue' ");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: "query result is same for all", but you have a problem with "i have just one result in all the column"?

Comment: Sorry, the result is not the same but  the values of that column are retrieved by the same query, but will be different for different rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table 
SET my_value = (select col from some_table where ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value is the same for all rows, I would advise using `cross join`:

```
update table t cross join
       (select newval . . .) x
    set t.col = x.newval;
```

Note:  this is better than a subquery, because the subquery is guaranteed to be evaluated only once.

If you are trying to say that the value is the same for *groups* of columns, then extend this to a `join`:

```
update table t join
       (select grp, newval . . .) x
       on t.grp = x.grp
    set t.col = x.newval;
```

Answer (score 0):

> After adding the column I want to add the result of a query (query
>   result is same for all) into that column all at once instead of one at
>   a time which will be time consuming.

The solution depends on what you mean by "Is the same for all the rows."

If you have one value that is exactly the same for all columns, you can just ask for it and then update. This is usually faster (and allows you to debug more easily) than using pure SQL to achieve everything.

If, on the other hand, you mean the values of that column are retrieved by the same query, but will be different for different rows, then a subquery or a cross join as [Gordon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559705/2359271) will do the trick.